Best way to support Theming in MAUI?
I have seen two seperate ways to support theming

DynamicResource and switching in the relevant ResourceDictionary
AppThemeBinding

I am currently using the DynamicResource markup extension and a Light.xaml and Dark.xaml resource dictionary. This does not reflect the Platform setting and is simply a local Preferences setting. When the user selects one or the other I remove the existing and load the selected
ICollection<ResourceDictionary> mergedDictionaries = Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries;
if (mergedDictionaries != null)
{
    ResourceDictionary currentTheme = mergedDictionaries.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source != null && d.Source.ToString().Contains("Themes"));

    if (currentTheme != null)
    {
        mergedDictionaries.Remove(currentTheme);
    }
    
    if (this.IsDarkModeEnabled())
    {
        mergedDictionaries.Add(new Resources.Styles.Themes.Dark());
    }
    else
    {
        mergedDictionaries.Add(new Resources.Styles.Themes.Light());
    }
}

This does work although I have not fully implemented it yet but I noticed yesterday that the Styles that were added by the "Upgrade Assistant" (we are migrating from XF) use AppThemeBinding
For example
<Style TargetType="ActivityIndicator">
        <Setter Property="Color" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
</Style>

What is the approach that Microsoft is advocating?
What are others using?

Thats not what you should do, make a method that has all your DynamicResource for light theme and another one with all for Dark and when you need to switch this just call the right method and you are good

That sounds like a third approach. Do you not use AppThemeBinding? What do you mean by "make a method that has all your DynamicResource...". Are you saying my current approach won't work? It seems to

You can refer to Respond to system theme changes on how to implement Theming in MAUI.
